# Wufoo: update entry using API

Tags: wufoo

Using Wufoo's API, is it possible (and if so how) to retrieve a single entry and update the information in it (without submitting it as another entry)? I can't seem to find any information on the Wufoo API website. If this isn't possible, any suggestions as to to work around this (such as using a local db). I'd like to build a hybrid app that authenticates locally and uses Wufoo for the data collection.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a similar kind of project and ran into the same issue. After submitting a help ticket, I was informed that the wufoo API does NOT support this function (update). Any updates would have to be done externally.

Like you, I would like to store my data in wufoo rather than externally, so I'm working on a few scripts that will serve as webhook endpoints for my wufoo forms. Whenever a form is submitted, one of these scripts will receive that data, do stuff with it, then use the API to relay the modified data back to a second wufoo form that "shadows" the original (same fields if needed, or new fields that reflect the processing I did).

This second set of forms would be the final destination for the data and only be accessed by my code. The first set of forms would only be accessed by live users. In a nutshell, it's a huge feedback loop that uses webhooks to trigger the processing.

Hope this helps.

for more info on webhooks, see http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/Webhooks?q=webhook&fs=Search&pn=1

for more info on the wufoo api Entries api (get & post), see http://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/The-Entries-API

Comment: I ended up standing-up a [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com) instance and now host my own Wufoo app with full control of the api. Wufoo use to be great, but in the last couple of years they stopped productive development on it. (It was probably sold.)

Comment: wufoo was bought by surveymonkey.com